# Программирование С++

Tags: c++

здравствуйте! помогите с кодом плиз! нужно считать текст с одного фаила заменить знаки препинания как в телеграмме на "ТЧК","ЗПТ" и т.д вот мой код,но записывает тока "ТЧК" и зачикливается...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#define _UNICODE
using namespace std;

int main() 
{

FILE *fp=fopen("test.txt","rt");
FILE *ctel=fopen("telegramma.txt","at");

char out[100];
char MSsym[256];
int i=1;
if((fp)==NULL)
 {
 CharToOem("Îøèáêà ïðè îòêðûòèè ôàéëà. \n\r", out);
 cout << out;

 } 
else
    {
    CharToOem("Ôàéë îòêðûò. \n\r", out);
    cout << out;
    if((ctel)==NULL)
        {
        CharToOem("Îøèáêà ïðè îòêðûòèè ôàéëà. \n\r", out);
        cout << out;
        }
        else
            {
while(!feof(fp))
{
fgets(MSsym,256,fp);
cout << "sym =" << MSsym[i] << endl;
if (MSsym[i] = '.')

    fputs(" Ò×Ê ",ctel);

    else

        if (MSsym[i] = ',')

            fputs(" ÇÏÒ ",ctel);

        else

            if (MSsym[i] = '!')

                fputs(" ÂÑÊË ",ctel);

            else

                if (MSsym[i] = '?')

                    fputs(" ÂÏÐÑ ",ctel);

                else

                    if (MSsym[i] = '(')
                    fputs(" ÑÊË ",ctel);

                    else

                    if (MSsym[i] = ')')

                            fputs(" ÑÊÏ ",ctel);

    else

        fputs(MSsym,ctel);
        i=i++;

}       
}
}
        fclose(fp);
        fclose(ctel);

getchar();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Andrewakim, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: ну хотя бы видно, что сам писал

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень сложный для понимания код.
Вот простое решение, модифицируй на здоровье!

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string toFormat( char c ){
        switch ( c ){
                case '.' :  return "ТЧК";
                case ',' :  return "ЗПТ";
                default:    return string(1, c);    //Нет конструктора только для char, есть для const char* и заполнение size_t, char.
            }
    }

int main(){

    ifstream inp;
    ofstream out;

    inp.open("input.txt");
    out.open("output.txt");

    while( ! inp.eof() ){
            out << toFormat( inp.get() );
        }

    inp.close(); out.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я бы еще пробел добавил перед строками "ТЧК" и "ЗПТ" для удобочитаемости.